# how to find collegue Id in table

Tags: sql

i have one table as Employee that have two column Id and Branch. i have to find its collegue Id except his own id from table without using subquery.

```
Id      Branch
==============
1       Delhi
2       Mumbai
3       Delhi
4       Delhi
5       Mumbai
6       Mumbai
```

if i enter e.g. 3 then my answer has to be 1 and 4.

Comment: Which type of Database are you using?

Comment: Have you tried `JOIN`ing the table to itself?

Answer (score 1):

Without a subquery means with a self join:

```
select tt.* 
from tablename t inner join tablename tt 
on t.Branch = tt.Branch and tt.id <> t.id
where t.id = 3
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cz9QW1Mjq46AxF7y2PtbeJ/1).

Answer (score 0):

use self join

```
  select t2.id from table_name t1 
  join table_name t2 on t1.Branch=t2.Branch
  where t1.id=3 and t2.id!=3
```

for data preparation easily i used CTE version below with result

```
 with cte as
(

select 1 as id, 'Delhi' as b
union all
select 2,    'Mumbai'
union all
select 3    ,  'Delhi'
union all
select 4  ,     'Delhi'

) select t2.id from cte t1 join cte t2 on t1.b=t2.b
  where t1.id=3 and t2.id!=3
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d8e54c1b5b9564bdc1209b7aaa42ea70)

here is the output

```
id
1
4
```

Comment: @melpomene thanks to you .but it seems some over loveable person did that but without explanation :)

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand why you were downvoted either. Your answer had the correct approach from the start and with those two minor edits it produces exactly what OP asked for.

Comment: @melpomene don't know sometimes it seems without properly understanding some people doing this kind of activity :)

Comment: Probably downvoter didn't see your edits. In any case, it is of course *kind* to leave a comment, but not a must, and no need to reveal ones votes in the comments.

Comment: @zx8754 down vote is always welcome but must have some explanation according to my opinion because without explanation its a nothing to find for improve answer

Comment: This is explained in meta many times over, see comments in this post by mods, Shog and ChrisF: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/228487 Downvoter is already spending their reps to downvote, so they had a reason to do so, no need to explain further.

Comment: thanks for the answer really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @mvcsharma for appreciation answer accepting also a way i just share if you dont know and  you can accept only one answer

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you the answer you're after:

```
SELECT  E1.Id
FROM    Employee E1
INNER
JOIN    Employee E2
        ON E1.[Branch] = E2.[Branch]
WHERE   E2.Id = 3
AND     E1.Id <> 3
```

It works by joining the `Employee` table onto itself, by `Branch` and then:

- `WHERE E2.Id = 3` - Where the Employee is Id # 3
- `AND E1.Id <> 3` - excluding any records from the *original* `Employee` table where `Id` is 3

Here's the script I used to create your test data (in SQL Server) for the purposes of validating the query:

```
CREATE TABLE [Employee]
( 
    [Id] INT,
    [Branch] NVARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT
INTO    [Employee]
        (
            Id,
            [Branch]
        )
VALUES  (1, 'Delhi'),
        (2, 'Mumbai'),
        (3, 'Delhi'),
        (4, 'Delhi'),
        (5, 'Mumbai'),
        (6, 'Mumbai')
```